# Derived functors in Categories Enriched Over Abelian Monoids

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

EDIT: Are there references to the literature that works out dervied functors for categories enriched over abelian monoids? (I narrowed down the question in the hope for an answer.)

Comment: In my book, semigroups have associative multiplication (or let us say addition in the abelian case). Since he assumes a neutral element, I assume he means commutative monoid, in which case I find this question to be a very natural one. If Colin doesn't mean to include associtativity as an axiom, I find the question far less natural. 

Comment: (Semigroups -abelian or not- are *defined* to be associative!)

Comment: Yeah, I was confused because Colin forgot to list associativity as one of the axioms (unless he really meant the non-associative analogue!).

Comment: (In case my initial comment seems confusing, it was in response to a comment of Harry which he later deleted.) 

Comment: yes. i do mean associative. usually i find the nomenclature "monoid" confusing. i find the analogy between ring and semiring, and group and semigroup.